# seeking information on CiviCRM 4.1 version of "CRM/Core/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php" file

Tags: drupal, payment-processor

The Vanco Payment Processor module uses a core file (*CRM/Core/BAO/PaymentProcessor.php*) in CiviCRM 4.1 that I'm unable to find in CiviCRM 4.4.  Does anyone have knowledge of the file and might know if it has been renamed or moved within the file structure?

Comment: Are the older versions of CiviCRM available to download?

Comment: Want to post that as another question?

Answer (score 6):

This was removed before CiviCRM moved to git, so I browsed the old Subversion repo.  I can see that revision 44887 removed it.  It's present if you click the first link but not the second:
http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/!svn/bc/44886/trunk/CRM/Core/BAO/
http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/!svn/bc/44887/trunk/CRM/Core/BAO/

I then attempted to view the SVN log, and then to check out the SVN repo:
svn log -v http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm 
svn checkout http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/trunk civicrm

Both failed with a 503 error, I suspect this is to blame:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/varnish-throwing-503-on-svn-requests/25828

So I Googled "civicrm r44887" and found an IRC log:

```
[08:54] <civi-bot> r44887 by yashodha: CRM-11334 -- https://fisheye2.atlassian.com/changelog/CiviCRM?cs=44887
```

So there are your answers!  Check that atlassian.com link and CRM-11334, you'll find what you're looking for.

Comment: @mike_kc please accept this answer as correct by clicking on the tick beside it. SE works best if the answers are formally accepted.